# Beforeunload not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html

.html:

```
<html>
<header>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
heya!
</body>
</html>
```

.js:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    saveData();
}

function saveData() {
    return "HELLO";
}
```

I also tried:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    saveData();
    return true;
});
```

The only one I found working was to put:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return saveData()">
```

But even then it wouldn't show my message ("HELLO", just showed "Do you want to leave this page blabla") etc. I just want to be able to save stuff before page is closed, without an alert, but using an alert to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event `onbeforeunload` works properly.

If you want to make it to ask for the user if he wants to leave the page, you must return something:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return saveData();
}
```

But if you want to only do stuff in the background, before the page is left, you can put whatever you want inside the event, and it will work properly. Take a look at the example below (open your console):

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  console.log('leaving');
}
```

```html
<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'>Go to StackOverflow</a>
```

Note: if you use `prompt` or `alert`, some browsers won't allow, because they're obtrusive to the user.

Comment: It works fine if I put it in the main .html it seems, but not the external .js.